# docker container reachable despite firewall denying incoming traffic

Tags: linux, firewall, ufw

I am in the process of setting up a VPS to run a few docker packages.
The firewall set up to block any incoming traffic (default) just allowing anything that comes in via Wireguard VPN.

Still the website of a docker container (running on port 9443) can be reached from outside. Exactly this website I do not want to be accessible from outside.

Checking iptables I see that output:

```
Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2           tcp dpt:9443
```

Does that overrule the settings from ufw, even for external connections?
Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, based on your `docker run` or compose file settings where you specify port `9443`:

> **Note:**
>
> If you don't specify an IP address (i.e., `-p 80:80` instead of `-p 127.0.0.1:80:80`) when publishing a container's ports, Docker publishes the port on all interfaces (address `0.0.0.0`) by default. These ports are externally accessible. **This also applies if you configured UFW to block this specific port**, as Docker manages its own iptables rules.
>
> https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_run/#publish

Docker ensures that incoming packets are always checked by the `DOCKER-USER` and `DOCKER` chains first. Do not edit them directly - you should adjust the way you launch the container instead. Read through this for more information on the firewall rules: https://docs.docker.com/network/packet-filtering-firewalls/

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not aware it bypasses the firewall settings.